# Spring batch reader changes to read file content from GCP cloud storage bucket

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, spring-batch

I have a pre existing springboot application like [this one](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-batch-example-1) which uses [spring batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) to read a huge CSV file(size=1GB) from a local location and inserts the content after some changes to a database. Now, the file will be coming from a bucket in Google Cloud Platform(GCP). I am planning to use something like Inbound streaming channel adapter mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_integration.html). Is this feasible?If yes, what changes will be needed in the ItemReader of the batch? Or is there any other option I need to consider? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The `FlatFileItemReader` works with any `Resource` implementation. So you could use an [`URLResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) and point it to your file on GCP without having to download it.

Here’s a specific [example](https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/doc/javadoc/edu/duke/URLResource.html) for a CSV file using the URLResource:

```java
URLResource ur = new URLResource("http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/java/food.csv");
 for (CSVRecord record : ur.getCSVParser()) {
     // print or process fields in record
     String name = record.get("Name");
     // other processing
 }
```

This was extracted from non-official documentation.

Comment: Thank you. If I understood correctly, if my bucket file's url is "https://storage.googleapis.com/test-mybucket/mycsv.csv", is the code going to look like this?
In this case, file content will be streamed directly?

flatFileItemReader.setResource(new URLResource("https://storage.googleapis.com/test-mybucket/mycsv.csv"));

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine is it fine to read the file from the network, wouldn't it be cumbersome rather than this. Why don't we download entire file in one go and then process the locally available file using multithreading?

Comment: @ZahidKhan Good question! The reason is that sometimes you don't have enough space locally to download the file. And in some cloud environments, there is no storage at all where you run the batch app (GCP did not provide support for `java.io.File` for a long time!). In those situations, it is better (if not even mandatory) to stream the file directly from the remote location.

Answer (score -1):

by adding relevant dependencies and changing the local file path

->"flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/message.csv"));"

to this

->"flatFileItemReader.setResource(new UrlResource("storage.googleapis.com/test-mybucket/mycsv.csv"));"

will it work ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: A humble suggestion to use formatting in answers using the { } icon . This helps to understand programmers which are particulary new . Thanks